# Error with command iotop on CentOS

Tags: centos, python, iotop

When using `sudo iotop` (latest version `0.6-2.el7`) in a terminal in my newly installed CentOS 7.5, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sbin/iotop", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 620, in main
    main_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 610, in <lambda>
    main_loop = lambda: run_iotop(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 508, in run_iotop
    return curses.wrapper(run_iotop_window, options)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/curses/wrapper.py", line 43, in wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 501, in run_iotop_window
    ui.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 155, in run
    self.process_list.duration)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 434, in refresh_display
    lines = self.get_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 415, in get_data
    return list(map(format, processes))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 388, in format
    cmdline = p.get_cmdline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/iotop/data.py", line 292, in get_cmdline
    proc_status = parse_proc_pid_status(self.pid)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/iotop/data.py", line 196, in parse_proc_pid_status
    key, value = line.split(':\t', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

**Any idea how to fix this problem?**

Comment: It works for me.
uname:
Linux 4.4.0-127-generic #153~14.04.1-Ubuntu
iotop version:
iotop 0.6
Phyton version
/usr/bin/python2.7

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Apparently, recent kernel versions introduced a blank line in `/proc/(pid)/status` that iotop does not expect:

```
CapBnd: 0000001fffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
Seccomp:    0

SpeculationStoreBypass: vulnerable
```

As a zeroth approximation of a fix, edit (as root) `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/iotop/data.py` ca l.195:

```
def parse_proc_pid_status(pid):
    result_dict = {}
    try:
        for line in open('/proc/%d/status' % pid):
            if not line.strip(): continue
            key, value = line.split(':\t', 1)
            result_dict[key] = value.strip()
    except IOError:
        pass  # No such process

    return result_dict
```

where the `if not line.strip(): continue` is new. Beware that python does not have explicit braces, so the indentation of this line should match that of the line below it.

(Also see https://bugs.launchpad.net/pkg-website/+bug/1773383 for other fixes for this bug.)

Comment: Here is a link to the CentOS bug covering this issue: https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=14864

Comment: Same for "Pympler" Python package. Line 147. Add `if not entry.strip(): continue` before to solve that problem. https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/

Comment: worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Just to complement the accepted answer (couldn't add as comment because they don't allow multiple white spaces)

1. Search for the filepath of the Python script

```
sudo find ./usr/lib | grep iotop/data.py
```

2. Replace with sed

```
sed -i '1n;/key, value = line/i\            if not line.strip(): continue' <script_path>
```

Be careful and check everything is ok the first time you run it.

For my systems, it is:

```
sudo sed -i '1n;/key, value = line/i\            if not line.strip(): continue' /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/iotop/data.py
```